# Why does publishing of events in a Sitecore bucket stop working after 100+ events were created and published one day?

Tags: sitecore-client

In a bucket in Sitecore, users have been creating and publishing events with no problem. On one day in September 2021, a user created and published more than 100 events over three hours. All these events were not displayed in CM and CD. Since that day, the new events created and published by users are also not displayed in CM and CD.

Here is an example of how the xxx events bucket is organized in this way:

xxx events
2021 (Year)
01 (Month)
06 (Day)
10 (Hour)
15 (Minute)
08 (Second)
Item

We looked into indexing and found that the new events were indexed, so indexing is not the issue.

We tried different things but none of them resolved the issue:

1. Deleted the folder with the 100+ events.
2. Delete all the folders under the September bucket.
3. Deleted the September folder.
4. Deleted other folders under September.
5. Deleted other folders under 2021.

We found that the only way to make publishing work again is to make the September bucket unpublishable in Publish|Change or to delete it.

However, we are clueless as to why the September bucket is the culprit after the user published 100+ events one day in September.

Could someone shed light on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: How are you pulling the data out of the CMS?

Comment: Check in your `web` database if there are some month (or year) folders which are not in `master` db. Eg content author created '09' folder for September, published it, but then removed it from `master` database without unpublishing first.  And then they created second '09' folder with events inside it. Now when you get `09` folder from your code, it's getting the old empty one instead of a new one with all the events.

Comment: @Marek Musielak Thanks for the pointer. Both the master and web databases have the same 09 folder with the same items. I copied the bucket to QA and that's where I found that the only way to make the event publishing work again is by making the 09 folder unpublishable or deleting it. I also checked that the 09 folder in both web and master databases in QA is identical.